# Ruby - Where to put resource files that a module in lib relies on?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9.3

I am trying to structure my ruby project following best practices.  I currently have something like this:

```
test_project/
   bin/
       test_project # My Executable
   lib/
       test_project/
           my_module.rb
       test_project.rb # Loads my_module.rb
```

I setup it up this way based on recommendations I found on the web.

My problem is I have some resource files, "resouce1.txt" and "resouce2.txt".  My executable   needs to open the file "resource1.txt".  my_module.rb needs to be able to open the file "resource2.txt".  Where do I put these plan text resource files in this directory structure and how to I open them (File.open) from the corresponding ruby files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `/lib` has to do with specifically the Ruby that powers your gems, I would put it in a top-level directory in your gem named after their subject matter. If they are files with lists of species I would call it `/species`.

You could also go the Rails way and put it in an `/assets` folder if you have a lot of external assets like `/assets/species`. Either way, I would not be prone to put them in `/lib`.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to load them with File.open?  For instance I think something like File.open "../../../assets/species" might get a little hard to manage.  Overall I think this is a good suggestion just wondering if there is a better way to figure out the path from the ruby file nested under lib.

Comment: I would add helper methods to the top level module/class of my gem, like `gem_path` and `assets_path` or `load_asset("species/1.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard place for these, as for the most part it is operating system dependent (`/var` and `/etc` vs `Program Files` vs the Application Bundle). But your best bet (I think) is to either put them in the root of your hierarchy, put them in `lib/` or, if they really are static text files, put them in your script.